# Motivating the coefficient field of $\ell$-adic cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ho.history-overview, cohomology

It was already known to Weil that a sufficiently reasonable cohomology theory for algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{F}_p$ would allow for a possible solution to the Weil conjectures.

It was also understood that such a cohomology theory could not take values in vector spaces over either the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ or the $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_p$. The classical argument that I know is that the cohomology of a supersingular elliptic curve should admit an action by a quaternion algebra structure of the endomorphism group of the elliptic curve, and representation theory rules out such an action. (Side question: Due to whom is this reasoning, and was it known to Weil's generation?)

This reasoning does not, however, rule out the possibility of cohomology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}_\ell$ with $\ell \neq p$, and indeed $\ell$-adic cohomology would end up being found.

**Question.** Were there any other historical reasons to believe that looking at cohomology valued in $\mathbb{Q}_\ell$-vector spaces would lead to something fruitful?

N.B. This question was posted on MathSE, but I got advised to post it here instead.

Comment: The argument with supersingular elliptic curves and quaternion algebras is due to Serre, I believe.

Comment: (See 1.7, p. 315 in Grothendieck's "Crystals and the de Rham cohomology of schemes", "As Serre has pointed out...")

Comment: It is not true that etalé cohomology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}_\ell$ is a "good" cohomology. $\ell$-adic cohomology is something more involved that just "cohomology with coefficients": its is the projective limit of some with finite coefficients (and tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: @Xarles That is of course what I meant. It takes values in $\mathbb{Q}_\ell$-modules, anyway. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One historical reason for considering $\ell$-adic cohomology, not completely disconnected from the example you introduce, is that for a curve over a field, we get a natural Galois representation by taking the $\ell$-adic Tate module of the Jacobian (i.e., the projective limit of $\ell$-power torsion).  Furthermore, if such a curve is defined over a subfield of the complex numbers, then the rank of the Tate module is equal to the rank of the classical degree 1 cohomology of the complexified curve.  We now know that the Tate module is naturally dual to étale cohomology in degree 1.

One might then reasonably hope for a similar relationship between the higher degree classical cohomology of higher dimensional varieties and certain $\ell$-adic Galois representations naturally attached to the variety.

Answer (score 3):

I think an important motivation for the $\ell$-adic theory comes from the Riemann existence theorem/the Grauert–Remmert theorem. This says that a finite (topological) covering space $Y \to X$ of a normal complex variety can again be equipped with an algebraic structure, which is more or less what you need to prove to obtain
$$\pi_1^{\operatorname{\acute et}}(X) = \widehat{\pi_1^{\operatorname{top}}(X(\mathbf C))}.$$
So finite covering spaces can be detected using the étale topology (except it's not really a topology, but that's not stopping Grothendieck!).

In particular, you expect to get a good theory of étale cohomology with *finite* coefficients. But to run the arguments that Weil was dreaming of, you need characteristic $0$ coefficients, so what do you do? Just take a limit!

I think that's really the explanation of why the adic formalism enters the picture. But it doesn't quite explain why it's different at the prime $p$. There are a few ways to look at this:

- Serre's argument shows that a $\mathbf Q_p$-valued Weil cohomology theory cannot exist (over any ground field $k$ containing $\mathbf F_{p^2}$; so in particular for $k = \bar{\mathbf F}_p$).
- The basic results on $\ell$-adic étale cohomology take the Galois cohomology of function fields of curves over algebraically closed fields as a starting point, and these behave differently at the prime $p$.
- Already for elliptic curves, the $p$-adic Tate module behaves a little different from the $\ell$-adic one.

In the end it doesn't really matter, because all they needed was *one* Weil cohomology theory.

Comment: Serre only shows that there is no $\mathbf{Q}$-linear Weil cohomology, at least if we restrict to algebraic varieties over a field which contains $\mathbf{F}_{p^2}$. If we work over $\mathbf{F}_p$, crystalline cohomology actually is a $\mathbf{Q}_p$-linear Weil cohomology, and I am not aware of an argument which rules out the existence of $\mathbf{Q}$-linear one. Your assertion that "it does not matter" can also be discussed: independence of $\ell$ problems have a long history which seem to point in a rather different direction.

Comment: It might also be worth mentionning that the standard conjectures together with tannakian arguments imply the existence of a $\bar{\mathbf{Q}}$-linear Weil cohomology.

Comment: @Denis-CharlesCisinski thanks for your comments. Serre's argument depends on representations of the quaternion algebra over $\mathbf Q$ that splits at $p$ and $\infty$, so it equally rules out $\mathbf Q_p$- and $\mathbf R$-valued Weil cohomology theories (as soon as $k \supseteq \mathbf F_{p^2}$).

Comment: Also, the original question is about "historically, why $\mathbf Q_\ell$", and my point is that if you're trying to prove the Weil conjectures you only need one cohomology theory. (Of course I am aware of the interesting "independence of $\ell$" questions ― I even have a paper on it!)

Comment: Crystalline/rigid cohomology for $k$-varieties take values in $W(k)$. So $\mathbf{Q}_p$ is a possible field of coefficient for $k=\mathbf{F}_p$.

Comment: Therefore, if, as you wrote, we only need one Weil cohomology, we may take a $\mathbf{Q}_p$-linear one defined over $\mathbf{F}_p$... I still think your post is not completely accurate.

Comment: @Denis-CharlesCisinski agreed (but note that this imprecision was already present in the original question).

Comment: @Denis-CharlesCisinski Is there a place the Tannakian argument based on the standard conjectures is written?

Comment: @lemiller If $k$ is an algebraically closed field, then any $k$-linear tannakian category is neutral. That is due to Deligne for $k$ of char. $0$ and to Coulembrier in general as Theorem 6.4.1 in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.02452.pdf  Since the standard conjectures imply that pure motives form a tannakian category (see e.g. the proceedings of the Seattle conference of Yves André's book on motives, or Milne's papers on  motives), they imply the existence of a $\bar{\mathbf{Q}}$-linear Weil cohomology.